# How can I create custom keyboard shortcuts in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

When studying biology and mechanisms, it's very useful to take notes with arrows that illustrate a stepwise process: A --> B --> C and up/down arrows to denote increase/decrease. This is very straightforward in MS Word, as I just assign a key to the arrow symbols I need, but I would like to be able to do this in Google Docs so I can continue collaborating on my work.

I've come across [Google's keyboard shortcuts for Docs](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179738), but I'm specifically looking for a **custom** keyboard shortcut, which I can't seem to find anywhere.

If this feature isn't available in Google Docs, is there a clipboard-type program that would give me the same result? I'm on OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: I fall on this question by searching "how to change keyboard shortcut in Google Docs" solutions aren't relevants ...

Comment: I'm using userscript (works with a chrome extension). You could set shortcuts to highlight, change font colors, etc. See the option4 in https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85859/76816

Comment: @snoobdogg Your comment isn't relevant to this question, however you got here.  If you can't find an answer elsewhere, ask a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[nhinkle](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35853/354) gives the germ of the answer.

[Automatic Corrections](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57859&topic=1361462&ctx=topic)

Automatic corrections for **→** and **←** are included as defaults. You just need to add your own for **↑** and **↓**. (Maybe `|^` and `|v`?)

While editing a document,

> 1. Select Preferences from the Tools drop-down menu.
> 2. Either deselect the checkbox next to the word for which you'd like to disable text substitution, or press the "x" to the right of the word to delete the row.
>
> [image: automatic corrections screen shot]

Comment: What if I want the shortcut to invoke something only available from the UI? For instance, I frequently want to switch to a different font and back.

Comment: @Michael: That's a separate question and you should post it as such.

Answer (score 3):

In Google Docs, just typing `-->` and `<--` will yield `→` and `←` without requiring any shortcuts.