# How can I change the font of selected text within a cell in Google Sheets using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, text-formatting

I am attempting to change the font of selected text within a cell in Google Sheets using a keyboard shortcut.

[image]

- I have attempted the steps meant for google docs here: [How can I change the font in Google Docs just with keyboards shortcuts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53643/how-can-i-change-the-font-in-google-docs-just-with-keyboards-shortcuts) 
  None of these steps have worked for me while inside the cell.
- I have also tried creating a macro (tools -> macro) that manually selects the font that I want, however, this does not work.
- I have not been able to change an active selection from within a cell without using the mouse.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible to achieve manually:

[image: 0]

Unfortunately, it's only possible **with** the mouse, because the font selector can't be triggered from a cell that is being edited via keyboard shortcuts.  So the manual sequence is:

- select cell to be edited
- press <kbd>**`ENTER`**</kbd> to enter editing mode
- navigate further with <kbd>**`arrow keys`**</kbd>
- make a selection with holding <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`arrow keys`**</kbd>
- when text selected pick a font with your mouse