# Text Inserter Macros for Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to type a shortened text phrase and have Google Docs (or a third party extension) replace it with text provided to it by the user (me). It should work like [Dot Phrases](https://www.todayshospitalist.com/drowning-in-note-bloat/) in Epic.

Comment: Does this answer suit your question? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35854/53017 . If you add text replacements to this list, they'll work when typing in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Google Docs, Sheets, etc., one can use Google Scripting in the same way as one would use VBA to write macros for Word, Excel and so on.

The scripts are written in GoogleScript, which is an extension to JavaScript.

You can have such a script search a document (for example, a template) for the string(s) of text and replace them based on the contents of, say, a spreadsheet.

You can find more information here: [Google Apps Script - Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document)

Another possibility is if you want to replace as you type.

For that, Google has introduced [Smart Compose (AI powered) to Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9643962?hl=en) recently. This may not be what you are looking for, though.

What I believe you need is the Substitutions functionality. Under Tools -> Preferences-> Substitutions. You can configure there any string (e.g. #repl -> replace by this text). It will only replace with lowercase text, though.

Comment: Is there a way to inject custom "Tab Completes" for the Press Tab to Complete the phrase feature?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I believe I misread your question. Google has introduced Smart Compose (AI powered) to Docs recently. This may not be what you are looking for, though:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9643962?hl=en

What I believe you need is the Substitutions functionality.
Under Tools -> Preferences-> Substitutions.
You can configure there any string (e.g. #repl -> replace by this text). It will only replace with lowercase text, though.